# how to add two arrays together using a method

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, sum

I am trying to add to lists together. ( I know my class name is not right for it, but whatever)

The problem I am facing is where i have the code:

```
C[i] = v[i] + x[i];
```

it says the type of expression must be an array but resolved into a variable.....any suggestions how to get around with it and be able to add two arrays together using a method??

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class reverse {

    int n;
    double [] arr;


    public reverse( int input){

        n =input;
        arr = new double[n];

    }


    public double[] get_array(){

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            arr[i] = i + 1;

        }

        return arr;
    } 




    public  reverse add(reverse v, reverse x){

        reverse C = new reverse(3);
                for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            C[i] = v[i] + x[i];
            System.out.println(C[i]);
        }
                return C;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){


            reverse A = new reverse(5);
            reverse B = new reverse(5);
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString(A.get_array()));
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString(B.get_array()));

        }
    }
```

Comment: According to Java conventions the class name should start with capital-case. Naming your class "reverse" doesn't make sense and actually makes it confusing... when you create the "answer" object in: `reverse C = new reverse(3);` you should create it in the same length that `x` and `v` are - so you shouldn't arbitrarily pass `3` to the constructor. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get the individual arrays from `v` and `x` call `get_array()`. Also, by convention the method `get_array()` should be `getArray()` and the class `reverse` should be `Reverse`. To correctly size `C`, get the lengths of `v` and `x` and take the `max` (or the `min` if you only want elements that appear on both sides). Iterate and add the values, storing the result in `C`'s array. Something like,

```
public reverse add(reverse v, reverse x) {
    reverse C = new reverse(Math.max(v.n, x.n));
    double[] vals = C.get_array(), left = v.get_array(), right = x.get_array();
    for (int i = 0; i < C.n; i++) {
        if (i < left.length && i < right.length) {
            vals[i] = left[i] + right[i];
        } else if (i < left.length) {
            vals[i] = left[i];
        } else {
            vals[i] = right[i];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

As mentioned, if you only want to add elements present on both sides, then the code can be simplified. Use `Math.min` to get the correct length and you can eliminate the array length checks. Like,

```
public reverse add(reverse v, reverse x) {
    reverse C = new reverse(Math.min(v.n, x.n));
    double[] vals = C.get_array(), left = v.get_array(), right = x.get_array();
    for (int i = 0; i < C.n; i++) {
        vals[i] = left[i] + right[i];
    }
    return C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by saying `reverse C;`, you are not creating an array, therefore you cannot use C[i].

```
public  reverse add(reverse v, reverse x){
    reverse C = new reverse(3);
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        //Replace C with C.arr
        C.arr[i] = v[i] + x[i];
        System.out.println(C.arr[i]);
    }
    return C;   
}
```

Here `C.arr` refers to `arr` field in C

Also by convention type name should start with a capitalized letter

Answer (score 0):

C,v, and x are Objects of type Reverse, not arrays.  You need to access the arrays within the objects.

```
C.arr[i] = v.arr[i] + x.arr[i];
System.out.println(C.arr[i]);
```

Also, you don't allow for the fact that they might not be the same size arrays.  You might need to allow for that.